# Pregmatch to fetch 'v1.0' WebcamJS in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match

I need pregmatch to fetch 'v1.0' from the first comment line

I tried this, but its not working for me '@[\s\S]*(?<=WebcamJS )([0-9.]+)@' [permalink](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9LW)

```
// WebcamJS v1.0 - http://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs - MIT Licensed
(function(e){var Webcam={version:"1.0.0",protocol:location.protocol.match(/https/i)?"https":"http",swfURL:"",loaded:false,live:false,userMedia:true,params:{width:0,height:0,dest_width:0,dest_height:0,image_format:"jpeg",jpeg_quality:90,force_flash:false},hooks:{load:null,live:null,uploadcomplete:null,uploadprogress:null,error:function(e){alert("Webcam.js Error: "+e)}},init:function(){navigator.getUserMedia=navigator.getUserMedia||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia||navigator.mozGetUserMedia||navigator.msGetUserMedia;e.URL=e.URL||e.webkitURL||e.mozURL||e.msURL;this.userMedia=this.userMedia&&!!navigator.getUserMedia&&!!e.URL;if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\D+(\d+)/)){if(parseInt(RegExp.$1,10)<21)this.userMedia=null}},attach:function(t){if(typeof t=="string"){t=document.getElementById(t)||document.querySelector(t)}if(!t){return this.dispatch("error","Could not locate DOM element to attach to.")}this.container=t;t.innerHTML="";var a=document.createElement("div");t.appendChild(a);this.peg=a;if(!this.params.width)this.params.width=t.offsetWidth;if(!this.params.height)this.params.height=t.offsetHeight;if(!this.params.dest_width)this.params.dest_width=this.params.width;if(!this.params.dest_height)this.params.dest_height=this.params.height;if(this.params.force_flash)this.userMedia=null;var i=this.params.width/this.params.dest_width;var s=this.params.height/this.params.dest_height;if(this.userMedia){var r=document.createElement("video");r.setAttribute("autoplay","autoplay");r.style.width=""+this.params.dest_width+"px";r.style.height=""+this.params.dest_height+"px";if(i!=1||s!=1){t.style.overflow="hidden";r.style.webkitTransformOrigin="0px 0px";r.style.mozTransformOrigin="0px 0px";r.style.msTransformOrigin="0px 0px";r.style.oTransformOrigin="0px 0px";r.style.transformOrigin="0px 0px";r.style.webkitTransform="scaleX("+i+") scaleY("+s+")";r.style.mozTransform="scaleX("+i+") scaleY("+s+")";r.style.msTransform="scaleX("+i+") scaleY("+s+")";r.style.oTransform="scaleX("+i+") scaleY("+s+")";r.style.transform="scaleX("+i+") scaleY("+s+")"}t.appendChild(r);this.video=r;var o=this;navigator.getUserMedia({audio:false,video:true},function(t){r.src=e.URL.createObjectURL(t)||t;Webcam.stream=t;Webcam.loaded=true;Webcam.live=true;Webcam.dispatch("load");Webcam.dispatch("live")},function(e){return o.dispatch("error","Could not access webcam.")})}else{var h=document.createElement("div");h.innerHTML=this.getSWFHTML();t.appendChild(h)}if(this.params.crop_width&&this.params.crop_height){var n=Math.floor(this.params.crop_width*i);var l=Math.floor(this.params.crop_height*s);t.style.width=""+n+"px";t.style.height=""+l+"px";t.style.overflow="hidden";t.scrollLeft=Math.floor(this.params.width/2-n/2);t.scrollTop=Math.floor(this.params.height/2-l/2)}else{t.style.width=""+this.params.width+"px";t.style.height=""+this.params.height+"px"}},reset:function(){if(this.preview_active)this.unfreeze();if(this.userMedia){try{this.stream.stop()}catch(e){}delete this.stream;delete this.video}this.container.innerHTML="";delete this.container;this.loaded=false;this.live=false},set:function(){if(arguments.length==1){for(var e in arguments[0]){this.params[e]=arguments[0][e]}}else{this.params[arguments[0]]=arguments[1]}},on:function(e,t){e=e.replace(/^on/i,"").toLowerCase();if(typeof this.hooks[e]=="undefined")throw"Event type not supported: "+e;this.hooks[e]=t},dispatch:function(){var t=arguments[0].replace(/^on/i,"").toLowerCase();var a=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);if(this.hooks[t]){if(typeof this.hooks[t]=="function"){this.hooks[t].apply(this,a)}else if(typeof this.hooks[t]=="array"){this.hooks[t][0][this.hooks[t][1]].apply(this.hooks[t][0],a)}else if(e[this.hooks[t]]){e[this.hooks[t]].apply(e,a)}return true}return false},setSWFLocation:function(e){this.swfURL=e},getSWFHTML:function(){var t="";if(location.protocol.match(/file/)){return'<h1 style="color:red">Sorry, the Webcam.js Flash fallback does not work from local disk.  Please upload it to a web server first.</h1>'}if(!this.swfURL){var a="";var i=document.getElementsByTagName("script");for(var s=0,r=i.length;s<r;s++){var o=i[s].getAttribute("src");if(o&&o.match(/\/webcam(\.min)?\.js/)){a=o.replace(/\/webcam(\.min)?\.js.*$/,"");s=r}}if(a)this.swfURL=a+"/webcam.swf";else this.swfURL="webcam.swf"}if(e.localStorage&&!localStorage.getItem("visited")){this.params.new_user=1;localStorage.setItem("visited",1)}var h="";for(var n in this.params){if(h)h+="&";h+=n+"="+escape(this.params[n])}t+='<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" codebase="'+this.protocol+'://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="'+this.params.width+'" height="'+this.params.height+'" id="webcam_movie_obj" align="middle"><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /><param name="movie" value="'+this.swfURL+'" /><param name="loop" value="false" /><param name="menu" value="false" /><param name="quality" value="best" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><param name="flashvars" value="'+h+'"/><embed id="webcam_movie_embed" src="'+this.swfURL+'" wmode="opaque" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="'+this.params.width+'" height="'+this.params.height+'" name="webcam_movie_embed" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="'+h+'"></embed></object>';return t},getMovie:function(){if(!this.loaded)return this.dispatch("error","Flash Movie is not loaded yet");var e=document.getElementById("webcam_movie_obj");if(!e||!e._snap)e=document.getElementById("webcam_movie_embed");if(!e)this.dispatch("error","Cannot locate Flash movie in DOM");return e},freeze:function(){var e=this;var t=this.params;if(this.preview_active)this.unfreeze();var a=this.params.width/this.params.dest_width;var i=this.params.height/this.params.dest_height;var s=t.crop_width||t.dest_width;var r=t.crop_height||t.dest_height;var o=document.createElement("canvas");o.width=s;o.height=r;var h=o.getContext("2d");this.preview_canvas=o;this.preview_context=h;if(a!=1||i!=1){o.style.webkitTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.mozTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.msTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.oTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.transformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.webkitTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.mozTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.msTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.oTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.transform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")"}this.snap(function(){o.style.position="relative";o.style.left=""+e.container.scrollLeft+"px";o.style.top=""+e.container.scrollTop+"px";e.container.insertBefore(o,e.peg);e.container.style.overflow="hidden";e.preview_active=true},o)},unfreeze:function(){if(this.preview_active){this.container.removeChild(this.preview_canvas);delete this.preview_context;delete this.preview_canvas;this.preview_active=false}},savePreview:function(e,t){var a=this.params;var i=this.preview_canvas;var s=this.preview_context;if(t){var r=t.getContext("2d");r.drawImage(i,0,0)}e(t?null:i.toDataURL("image/"+a.image_format,a.jpeg_quality/100),i,s);this.unfreeze()},snap:function(e,t){var a=this;var i=this.params;if(!this.loaded)return this.dispatch("error","Webcam is not loaded yet");if(!this.live)return this.dispatch("error","Webcam is not live yet");if(!e)return this.dispatch("error","Please provide a callback function or canvas to snap()");if(this.preview_active){this.savePreview(e,t);return null}var s=document.createElement("canvas");s.width=this.params.dest_width;s.height=this.params.dest_height;var r=s.getContext("2d");var o=function(){if(this.src&&this.width&&this.height){r.drawImage(this,0,0,i.dest_width,i.dest_height)}if(i.crop_width&&i.crop_height){var a=document.createElement("canvas");a.width=i.crop_width;a.height=i.crop_height;var o=a.getContext("2d");o.drawImage(s,Math.floor(i.dest_width/2-i.crop_width/2),Math.floor(i.dest_height/2-i.crop_height/2),i.crop_width,i.crop_height,0,0,i.crop_width,i.crop_height);r=o;s=a}if(t){var h=t.getContext("2d");h.drawImage(s,0,0)}e(t?null:s.toDataURL("image/"+i.image_format,i.jpeg_quality/100),s,r)};if(this.userMedia){r.drawImage(this.video,0,0,this.params.dest_width,this.params.dest_height);o()}else{var h=this.getMovie()._snap();var n=new Image;n.onload=o;n.src="data:image/"+this.params.image_format+";base64,"+h}return null},configure:function(e){if(!e)e="camera";this.getMovie()._configure(e)},flashNotify:function(e,t){switch(e){case"flashLoadComplete":this.loaded=true;this.dispatch("load");break;case"cameraLive":this.live=true;this.dispatch("live");break;case"error":this.dispatch("error",t);break;default:break}},b64ToUint6:function(e){return e>64&&e<91?e-65:e>96&&e<123?e-71:e>47&&e<58?e+4:e===43?62:e===47?63:0},base64DecToArr:function(e,t){var a=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g,""),i=a.length,s=t?Math.ceil((i*3+1>>2)/t)*t:i*3+1>>2,r=new Uint8Array(s);for(var o,h,n=0,l=0,c=0;c<i;c++){h=c&3;n|=this.b64ToUint6(a.charCodeAt(c))<<18-6*h;if(h===3||i-c===1){for(o=0;o<3&&l<s;o++,l++){r[l]=n>>>(16>>>o&24)&255}n=0}}return r},upload:function(e,t,a){if(a)Webcam.on("uploadComplete",a);var i="webcam";var s="";if(e.match(/^data\:image\/(\w+)/))s=RegExp.$1;else throw"Cannot locate image format in Data URI";var r=e.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/,"");var o=new XMLHttpRequest;o.open("POST",t,true);if(o.upload&&o.upload.addEventListener){o.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(e){if(e.lengthComputable){var t=e.loaded/e.total;Webcam.dispatch("uploadProgress",t,e)}},false)}o.onload=function(){Webcam.dispatch("uploadComplete",o.status,o.responseText,o.statusText)};var h=new Blob([this.base64DecToArr(r)],{type:"image/"+s});var n=new FormData;n.append(i,h,i+"."+s.replace(/e/,""));o.send(n)}};Webcam.init();if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define(function(){return Webcam})}else if(typeof module==="object"&&module.exports){module.exports=Webcam}else{e.Webcam=Webcam}})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
/\/\/\s*WebcamJS\s*v([0-9.]+)/i
```